# Mysql Show records where timestamp interval is lower then 4 minutes

Tags: mysql, timestamp

let's assume i have follow table

---

|  ID  |  teamid   | timestamp           |

|  5    |    1     | 2013-07-27 10:19:00 |

|  6    |    2     | 2013-07-27 10:20:00 |

|  7    |    1     | 2013-07-27 10:25:00 |

|  8    |    3     | 2013-07-27 10:26:00 |

|  9    |    1     | 2013-07-27 10:28:00 |

|  10   |    2     | 2013-07-27 10:29:00 |

|  11   |    3     | 2013-07-27 10:30:00 |

|  13   |    3     | 2013-07-27 10:31:00 |

What i need is the records where the interval between the timestamp is lower then 4 minutes and grouped by the team id

so output need looks like

| 7  |  1  | 2013-07-27 10:25:00 |

| 9  |  1  | 2013-07-27 10:28:00 |

| 11 | 3   | 2013-07-27 10:30:00 |

| 13 | 3   | 2013-07-27 10:31:00 |

can someone show me the correct way to solve

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sql statement will return your desired list:

**SELECT**   table1.id, table1.teamid, table1.timestamp
**FROM**     exampleTable table1, exampleTable table2
 **where**   table1.id != table2.id **AND** 
             table1.teamid = table2.teamid **AND** 
             ABS(table1.timestamp - table2.timestamp) < 400
**ORDER BY** teamid, id